# Teste de integração enviar e-mail

Tags: java, spring, envio-de-email, testes, criteria

Hoje tenho um sistema, que envia vários e-mails.

- Muitas configurações e regras de envio.
- Preciso adicionar umas 50 regras novas,  e-mails novos
- Formatos hora com arquivo em anexo, imagens e outras "cositas" mais.

Como esta hoje, uso um servidor de e-mail para autenticar e enviar os e-mail.

Porém preciso fazer uns testes de integração para validar essas regras!

- Como faria isso?
- Cadastrar script 50 usuários novos?
- Como validar o conteúdo desse e-mail, pelo menos algumas partes?
- Usando Mock? mas ai como testo? as criterias, as regras de negócio embutidas em todo esse cenário

  - **Descrição do cenário é complexo.**
  - Uso o Sprig 4.2
  - Uso Hibernate, criteria
  - JUnit
  - testNG
  - Themeleaf 3 para contruir os e-mail
  - As classes são muitas, Descrever as principais
  - DefinePropertie (define as propropriedades e-mail)
  - Classes que definem as camada de persistencia (@Service, @Repository)
  - Classes Quartz que executam e agendam as tarefas de enviar e-mail, conforme os estados dos objetos vão mudando
  - Classes que montam os e-mails
  - Classes que disparam os e-mails
  - Objetos @Component do Spring que Integram Quartz e fazem o link do serviços das classes que enviam o e-mail.

**Sugestões, porque a complexidade do cenário é bem grande**

Comment: Sugestão para validar conteúdo do e-mail, `Expression Regular`

Comment: Se usa `beanvalidation` tem a anotação `@Email`

Comment: Acho que vocês não entenderão, Expressão Regular ok, como captura tal e-mail para aplicar a validação? "beanvalidation tem a anotação @Email" o que quis dizer com isso?

Comment: Marcelo acho que a pergunta é muito ampla... Há multiplas maneiras de fazer esse tipo de coisa. Como você mesmo falou é possível mockar o serviço de autenticação e envio de e-mail (inspecionando por exemplo se o contéudo gerado em memória para o e-mail final condiz com os parâmetros de entrada mockados para cada "perfil" que ativaria uma regra). Você pode usar um servico como o [Mailtrap.io](https://mailtrap.io/), levantar um servidor SMTP Fake (e.g., [FakeSMTP](https://github.com/Nilhcem/FakeSMTP)) ou até um servidor SMTP real.

Comment: @Anthony gostei disso, FakeSMTP já usou isso? tem alguma sugestão para eu restringir o escopo da pergunta?

Comment: Não, mas já usei o [Dumbster](http://quintanasoft.com/dumbster/#Download). que [segue a mesma idéia](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16854993/664577). Também já tive que implementar meu próprio servidor de SMTP fake em um projeto para testes de aceitação (não recomendo, pague o Mailtrap.io :D). Eu diria para você brincar um pouco com as opções e ler artigos como [esse](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/09/testing-mail-code-in-spring-boot.html). Conforme você for entendo as técnicas as perguntas vão se tornando mais específicas. "Teste de integração para emails" é muito amplo.

Comment: Descreva um pouco mais sobre a sua arquitetura, quais são as classes que representam endereços de e-mails, mensagens de e-mails, usuários de e-mails, regras de filtragens, regras de encaminhamento, qual classe que envia o e-mail, etc. Caso contrário, qualquer resposta ou vai ser vaga e superficial demais para ser útil ou então vai depender de uma boa dose de especulação. Eu tentei escrever uma resposta, e cheguei a conclusão que simplesmente não dá porque a sua pergunta é ampla demais.

Comment: Tentei colocar um resumo do meu cenário, mas ele ainda é bem mais complexo do que descrevi, mas o que tem agora, já ilustra o tamanho da complexidade que tenho